# Angular [$interpolate:interr] error for applied filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-filters

Hi I have a filter which replaces **\n to \n\n** when i use this filter for my json data I get error saying `Can't interpolate: {{ post.description|nlToArray }}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

My filter

```
sampleApp.filter('nlToArray', function() {
  return function(text) {
      return text.replace(/\n/g, '/\n\n');
  };
});
```

displaying data obtained from json api

hmtl

```
<p class="blog-post-title">{{ post.title }}</p>
<p class="blog-post-meta"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp {{ post.pub_date|date  }}</i> </p>
<span style="white-space: pre-line">{{ post.description|nlToArray }}</span>
<br />
```

My json data

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Israel’s desert city of Beersheba is turning into a cybertech oasis","description":"morphing into a tech oasis.\r\nThe military’s massive relocation of its prestigious technology units.\r\nBeersheba has all of the ingredients of a vibrant security technology ecosystem, \r\n“All in all, projections are that 20,000-30,000 \r\nThe commercial sector has teamed up  cyber attacks.","pub_date":"2016-03-20T10:48:19.394643Z"},{"id":2,"title":"These are testing times: mavericks vs. ice people","description":"One of my earliest engineering jobs, before I fled hardware in favor of the (relative). \r\nThe practice of engineering soon teaches one that, .\r\nSo what do we do? We practice defense in depth. We follow the robustness principle. We “always code as \r\n…Yeah, well, that’s the idea. For my day job at HappyFunCorp I do a lot of interviews, and almost every junior develope.\r\nI don’t necessarily blame them. You can make  go.","pub_date":"2016-03-20T10:50:07.965930Z"}]
```

To be much clearer, description in json is like this

```
morphing into a tech oasis.\r\nThe military’s massive relocation of its prestigious technology units.\r\nBeersheba has all of the ingredients of a vibrant security technology ecosystem, \r\n“All in all, projections are that 20,000-30,000 \r\nThe commercial sector has teamed up  cyber attacks.
```

What could be the possible solution...Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you see if you remove the filter? Ie, just try and display `post.description` as-is

Comment: Ya but Im inserting 2 new line characters..........this is done by filter......If i remove filter it works fine

Comment: That's strange. You sure you don't have a typo in the function arguments, ie it definitely has `return function(text) { ...` and not `return function(txt)` or anything else?

Comment: Thanks Phil........Harpreet solution worked.......Thanks for your time to help me..........cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the code null safe by replacing

```
sampleApp.filter('nlToArray', function() {
  return function(text) {
      return text.replace(/\n/g, '/\n\n');
  };
});
```

with

```
sampleApp.filter('nlToArray', function() {
  return function(text) {
      if (text) 
        return text.replace(/\n/g, '/\n\n');
      else
        return text;
  };
});
```

Comment: @Coeus I'm not at all sure why this worked. At a guess, I'd say at least one of your data entries does **not** have a `description` property

Comment: @Phil: Coeus answered it, also it was mentioned in error logs in original post :)